# How to define two dependent generic interfaces?

Tags: c#

I encountered a problem while using a generic interface. Initial condition was as follows:

```
interface Itemplate1
{
    ...
}

interface Itemplate2<T> where T : Itemplate1
{
    ...
}
```

It works like a charm! But when I kept going to do rest of my application design, I noticed that `Itemplate1` members also need `Itemplate2`.

```
interface Itemplate1<T> where T : Itemplate2<?>
{
    ...
}

interface Itemplate2<T> where T: Itemplate1<?>
{
    ...
}
```

How can I do it?
Many Thanks

Comment: It would help if you would describe the problem that the circular generic implementations are trying to solve.  It may be that there is a simpler way -- perhaps just defining the interfaces independently and having a class that needs both inherit from both instead of constructing a hierarchy.  It's hard to tell from the limited information you've given us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done exactly the same kind of thing in [my Protocol Buffers port](http://protobuf-csharp-port.googlecode.com). I have to warn you that it ends up being a bit of a pain, but it *does* work.

In my case I needed:

```
public interface IMessage<TMessage, TBuilder>
    where TMessage : IMessage<TMessage, TBuilder>
    where TBuilder : IBuilder<TMessage, TBuilder>
```

and

```
public interface IBuilder<TMessage, TBuilder>
    where TMessage : IMessage<TMessage, TBuilder>
    where TBuilder : IBuilder<TMessage, TBuilder>
```

It's hard to say whether you'll need exactly the same pattern in your code or just something similar, but this has worked for me. Admittedly it helps that the actual concrete implementations are autogenerated...